# How to set dark theme for Android Studio?

Tags: themes, android-studio

Generally I like the standard elementary theme a lot. But for my development environments I prefer dark ones. I can start Scratch in dark theme by adding `env GTK_THEME=elementary:dark` to `Exec` command in its .desktop file. But I couldn't figure out how do get that working for Android Studio. If I enable dark theme for all applications in Elementary Tweaks, it works for Android Studio, too. But I really don't like all my Apps do be dark.

Android Studio with standard theme:
[image: Android Studio with standard theme]

Android Studio with dark theme:
[image: Android Studio with dark theme]

Is there a way to start only Android Studio with dark theme like it works with Scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately only GTK3.10+-applications with a HeaderBar are able to set specific themevariants.
For any other application there is a workaround:
[Gtk Theme Variant Switcher](https://github.com/oktayacikalin/gtk-theme-variant-switcher)

Install it and add the `WM_CLASS` of Android Studio, this should do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit. I've installed it but I don't know what to do next since it doesn't have a interface. How to add the WM_CLASS ? Can you post a screenshot ? Thanks in advance !